# How to get size of data being passed from one method to another in JProfiler?

Tags: jprofiler

I just started using JProfiler (version 11.0.1). After profiling my test application (instrumentation), I went to "CPU views->Call Graph" and generate the call graph after selecting the classes I am interested in. I have two classes, class A and class B. I see the time taken by each and the invocation count as well. All seems correct so far. In my example, I am passing an integer variable and a double variable from class A to class B. However, I don't know where to look for if I want to see how much data (say in terms of KB) is being sent from class A to class B. Here are the codes I have used:

Class A

```
public class ClassA {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ClassB clsB = new ClassB();
        clsB.MethodB1(78);
        clsB.MethodB2(999999);
    }
}
```

Class B

```
public class ClassB {
    public void MethodB1(int i){
        System.out.println("The value of i is " + i);
    }
    public void MethodB2(double i){
        System.out.println("The value of i is " + i);
    }
}
```

The result is as shown in the image below:
[image]

So, my question is where to look for the size of data being sent from ClassA to ClassB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring the size of objects passed between methods would be prohibitively expensive.

What you can do instead is use allocation recording in the memory views. Then you can see how may objects have been allocated at particular call stacks. With this information you may be able to answer your question.